# Simple tested regex not working in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

This is my tested [regex](https://regex101.com/r/aR1hT7/1):

```
(?:.*?- )(?<param_0>.*?)( Tu interés| Your main interest)(?:.*?- )(?<param_1>.*?) \)
```

with this input string:

```
Array ( [0] => Si es estudiante de intercambio, elija su país de origen: - No soy un estudiante de intercambio Tu interés en nuestra oferta de titulaciones se centra en los estudios de: - grado )
```

And this is my code:

```
$message = 'Si es estudiante de intercambio, elija su país de origen: - No soy un estudiante de intercambio Tu interés en nuestra oferta de titulaciones se centra en los estudios de: - grado ';
$regex = "/(?:.*?- )(?<param_0>.*?)( Tu inter| Your main interest)(?:.*?- )(?<param_1>.*?) \)/";

if (preg_match_all($regex, $message, $matches)) {
    $param_0 = matches[0];
    $param_1 = matches[1];
    echo 'Param 0: ';
    echo $param_0;
    echo '<br>Param 1: ';
    echo $param_1;
    echo '<br>';
} else {
    echo 'no match';
}
```

I guess it is some stupid error, but have barely used php and I cannot find the problem.

Comment: In your regex you also have `Array(` as string but not in your php code! Also your php code has like 5 syntax errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the regex part, you can use the *code generator* section. You have to escape some symbols, have a look at how it should be done (see `\\)/` at the end):

```
$re = "/(?:.*?- )(?<param_0>.*?)( Tu interés| Your main interest)(?:.*?- )(?<param_1>.*?) \\)/";
```

And you have:

```
$regex = "/(?:.*?- )(?<param_0>.*?)( Tu inter| Your main interest)(?:.*?- )(?<param_1>.*?) \)/";
```